# I have a problem with my datatable, My table has misaligned headers with data

Tags: javascript, datatables

[image]

options when I use datatable

```
var table = $('#table').DataTable({
  // orderCellsTop: true,  
  // searching: false,
  fixedHeader: true,
  //autoWidth: true,
  data: data,
  columnDefs: [{ width: '20%', targets: 0 }],
  fixedColumns: true,  
  scrollCollapse: true,
  scrollX: true,
  columns: [...]
```

i hope someone will teach me fix it

Comment: The number of headers must match the number of columns.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.